# setup scripting for Ubuntu

Tags: bash, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04

I am learning python and bash. I would like to setup a script with them so that I can run a single command to install these programs to work with python 3:

```
Pip
Pymongo
Mongodb
Setuptools
Xdg
Apt-get update
Boto3
opencv
```

How would I go about learning this or or are there some templates already out there?

Comment: With a shell script, remember that anything you type on the command-line can go into a script.  So figure out the commands you need and type them into a file using a text editor.  You now have a shell script which you can execute using `bash filename`.

Answer (score 0):

hi it`s about your question.
you just need to understand and function in bash
it is expressed with &&
Ex.

```
#!/bin/bash
function_name(){
apt-get install Pip &&
apt-get install Pymongo &&
apt-get install Mongodb &&
apt-get install Xdg &&
apt-get update &&
apt-get install Boto3 &&
apt-get install opencv
}
function_name
```

it is just way how to do it but i have 2 notes
1st note: "Dont forget to run script as superuser"
and second: "if you will type in last install '&&' you will reache to loop"

Comment: But you don't need a function here. Instead of using `&&` you could just `set -e`so that the script stops after the first error. Finally you could run `sudo apt-get` instead of plain `apt-get`. Since all commands are the same, you could just loop over the package names and install them.

Comment: it will not create loop i have tested it and if you just want to type 
root password 6 times you can do it i am just giving you answer to question and finally i thought that you should have been understanded that "and" is logic